# Does hiding php error messages increase security of the web app?

Tags: web-application, php

Many PHP frameworks such as Codeigniter on production environment opt-out to hide any PHP related error message. Also, that applies on other PHP frameworks as well such as Symphony and Laravel (with the appropriate settings).

So I wanted to know if this behavior increases slightly my web-app's security and how is security in increased.

Comment: Relevant: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138305/is-this-safe-to-display-mysql-query-error-in-webpage-if-something-went-wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never allow end users to gain insights into the inner workings of your system.
Doing so will allow a potential attacker to streamline his attacks and increase the chance that they will be successful.

For more information have a look at this:
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/200.html